# PlayOnLinux GTA San Andreas issues

Tags: playonlinux

I'm a complete newbie to ubuntu. I installed GTA San Andreas with PlayOnLinux. But whenever I click `run`, nothing happens. I used `debug mode` and then it shows me:

```
    Running wine-2.7 gta_sa.exe (Working directory : 
 /home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/gta/drive_c/Program Files/Rockstar Games/GTA San Andreas)

fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f528,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f518,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f308,0x00000000), stub!
```

I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: The "fixme" messages are not errors but for the maintainer to fix at some point. More than likely you are using an incorrect wine configuration or incorrect Wine version.

Comment: Soooo...what should i do then ?

Answer (score 2):

i did a research of my own and i managed to solve the issue by changing my wine version to 1.9.10 and deleting **gta_sa.set** from GTA San ANdreas User Files.

thank you all for your efforts.

Cheers..